# Oracle update every n number of rows with incremental number

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update

I have several tables which I need to update a number column ("BATCH") for N (variable) number of rows using an incremental counter starting with 1. Example: if the table has 1m records out of which 250,000 records fit a certain condition then first 100k of the 550k records should update BATCH column with number 1, the second 100k records should update with number 2, the remaining 50k records should update with 3.

Below was my attempt:

```
    v_cnt:=0;

    <<LoopBatch>>LOOP
    v_cnt_sql:='SELECT count(*)     
                FROM '||v_in_skinny_table||' 
                WHERE 
                    RECORD_STATUS IN '||v_in_mode||' 
                AND 
                    RECORD_STATUS != ''''00''';
--EXECUTE DYNAMIC SQL AND HOLD VALUE IN l_exst      
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_cnt_sql INTO l_exst;

    dbms_output.put_line(v_cnt_sql);    
    dbms_output.put_line(l_exst);

--IF MORE THAN 0 RECORDS EXIST
    IF
        l_exst>0
    THEN
        v_cnt:=v_cnt+1;
        v_dyn_sql:= 'UPDATE CONV_NL.'||v_in_skinny_table||'
                            SET BATCH='||v_cnt||' 
                            WHERE
                                RECORD_STATUS != ''''00''''
                            AND 
                                RECORD_STATUS IN '||v_in_mode||'
                            AND
                                ROWNUM < '||v_in_source_batch_size; --THIS IS THE VARIABLE BATCH SIZE OR NUMBER OF ROWS

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dyn_sql;
        COMMIT;
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Can someone please guide me to the right direction. I hope I didn't miss any relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was totally misled with the question initially!

This ...

```
SET BATCH = CEIL(ROWNUM/v_in_source_batch_size)
```

... is just enough to update all at one shot? And you **don't** need *LOOPs*
(If you can `COMMIT` everything finally)

```
    v_dyn_sql:= 'UPDATE CONV_NL.'||v_in_skinny_table||'
                        SET BATCH=CEIL(ROWNUM/'||v_in_source_batch_size||') 
                        WHERE
                            RECORD_STATUS != ''''00''''
                        AND 
                            RECORD_STATUS IN '||v_in_mode;
```

`ROWNUM` corresponds with the row it updates. `CEIL()` rounds up to the nearest whole number:  `CEIL(1/10)` gives 1 only, so too...(2/10)...( 10/10). So, `CEIL(ROWNUM/10)` .. is 1 for first 10 rows...2 for next 10 rows.. etc. 10 here is the Batchsize.

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes sense, can you elaborate what this will do?

Comment: `ROWNUM` corresponds with the row it update.. CEIL(1/10)..(2/10).. 10/10.... gives 1 only.. So, `CEIL(ROWNUM/10)` .. is 1 for first 10 rows...2 for next 10 rows.. etc.. 10 here is the Batchsize.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24fe3/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  RECORD_STATUS VARCHAR2(4),
  ID            NUMBER(30),
  BATCH         NUMBER(1)
);

INSERT INTO Test
SELECT '''00''', LEVEL, NULL
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

INSERT INTO Test
SELECT 'AAA', LEVEL + 5, NULL
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4;

INSERT INTO Test
SELECT 'BBB', LEVEL +9, NULL
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7;

INSERT INTO Test
SELECT 'CCC', LEVEL +16, NULL
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6;
```

**Query 1**:

```
UPDATE TEST
SET    BATCH = CEIL( ROWNUM / 3 )
WHERE  RECORD_STATUS <> '''00'''
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24fe3/1/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM Test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24fe3/1/1)**:

```
| RECORD_STATUS | ID |  BATCH |
|---------------|----|--------|
|          '00' |  1 | (null) |
|          '00' |  2 | (null) |
|          '00' |  3 | (null) |
|          '00' |  4 | (null) |
|          '00' |  5 | (null) |
|           AAA |  6 |      1 |
|           AAA |  7 |      1 |
|           AAA |  8 |      1 |
|           AAA |  9 |      2 |
|           BBB | 10 |      2 |
|           BBB | 11 |      2 |
|           BBB | 12 |      3 |
|           BBB | 13 |      3 |
|           BBB | 14 |      3 |
|           BBB | 15 |      4 |
|           BBB | 16 |      4 |
|           CCC | 17 |      4 |
|           CCC | 18 |      5 |
|           CCC | 19 |      5 |
|           CCC | 20 |      5 |
|           CCC | 21 |      6 |
|           CCC | 22 |      6 |
```